# sql query count rows per id to by selecting range between 2 min dates in different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
       temp
|id|received  |changed   |ur|context|
|33|2019-02-18|2019-11-18|
|33|2019-08-02|2019-09-18|
|33|2019-12-27|2019-12-18|
|18|2019-07-14|2019-10-18|
|50|2019-03-20|2019-05-26|
|50|2019-01-19|2019-06-26|
```

```
       temp2
|id|min_received  |min_changed   |
|33|2019-02-18    |2019-09-18    |
|18|2019-04-14    |2019-09-18    |
|50|2019-01-11    |2019-05-25    |
```

The 'temp' table shows users who received a request for an activity. A user can make multiple requests. Hence the received column has multiple dates showing when the requests was received. The 'changed' table shows when the status was changed. There are also multiple values for it.

There is another temp2 column which shows the min dates for received and changed. Need to count total requests per user between the range of values in temp2

The expected result should look like this :- The third row of id- 33 should not be selected because the received date is after the changed date.

```
|id|total_requests_sent|
|33|2                  |
|18|1                  |
|50|2                  |
```

Tried Creating 2 CTE's for both MIN date values and joined with the original one

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question? [SQL Query to count between range of minimum date and date in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211659/sql-query-to-count-between-range-of-minimum-date-and-date-in-other-column)

Comment: The last table is has changing values now, it's not constant as before

Comment: It wouldn't be much different. Find min(received) and min(changed) for each user and subtract them to find the number of days. Count all positive numbers again.

Comment: So... `SELECT id, count(*) FROM temp WHERE received < changed`? That fits your definition here: *"The third row of id- 33 should not be selected because the received date is after the changed date."* Without the complexity of your first definition *"Need to find the COUNT of requests per user BETWEEN the MIN(received) date and MIN(changed) date"* which doesn't make any sense to me. If your requirement is more complex than this SQL solves, then please include sample data and desired results that represent that complexity or fix up your definition/requirement to something that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be really over-simplifying your task, but wouldn't something like this work?

```
select
  t.id, count (*) as total_requests_sent
from
  temp t
  join temp2 t2 on
    t.id = t2.id
where
  t.received between t2.min_received and t2.min_changed
group by
  t.id
```

I believe the output will match your example on the use case you listed, but with a limited dataset it's hard to be sure.